# how to define ssh keys in Ruby net/sftp connection?

Tags: ruby, ssh

```
require 'net/sftp'

Net::SFTP.start('ip', 'user', :keys => ['/home/user/.ssh/id_rsa.pub', '/home/user/.ssh/id_rsa'], :password => 'password', :port => 30) do |sftp|
puts 'connected'
end
```

or

```
Net::SFTP.start('ip', 'user', :password => 'password', :port => 30) do |sftp|
puts 'connected'
end
```

but not working..

what is correct way to do this ?

Answer (score 0):

Check that your .bashrc file does not echo any strange strings.  It must be clean.

You can test it by running the command `ssh <target> -s sftp`

eg:

```
Johns-MacBook-Pro:~ jcreasey$ ssh localhost -s sftp
Password:
fooo
```

Here my shell is echoing 'fooo' which breaks sftp
You can test if everything works using the `sftp` command.